# Solutions to $z^4-4z+\lambda=0$ with complex parameter $\lambda$, $|\lambda|<2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> For a complex parameter $\lambda$, $|\lambda|<2$, consider the
>     solutions to the equation
>     \begin{equation*}
>     z^4-4z+\lambda=0
>   \end{equation*}
>
> $(1)$ Show that there is exactly one solution $z(\lambda)$ to the
>       equation with $|z(\lambda)|<1$, and that
>
> $(2)$ Show that the function $\lambda\mapsto z(\lambda)$ is analytic for $|\lambda|<2$

I've done the $(1)$ using Rouche's theorem, and am completely stuck on the (2). I guess I probably should use some implicit function theorem or inverse function theorem, but can't write them down rigorously.

Any helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We prove that $\lambda \mapsto z(\lambda)$ is holomorphic at every point $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| < 2$.

In view of the inverse function theorem, it suffices to prove that the function $f(z) = 4z - z^{4}$ has non-vanishing derivative at $z = z(\lambda)$ for any $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| < 2$. But

$$f'(z) = 4 - 4z^{3} = 4(1 - z^{3}), $$

which cannot be zero if $|z| < 1$. Now we know that this is true for $z = z(\lambda)$ by (1). Therefore we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have known this type of argument.